# GCP - CDN Server

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-storage, server, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to architect a system on GCP for scalable web/app servers.  My initial intention was to have one disk per web server group hosting the OS, and another hosting the source code + imagery etc.  My idea was to mount the OS disk on multiple VM instances so to have exact clones of the servers, with one place to store PHP session files (so moving in between different servers would be transparent and not cause problems).

The second idea was to mount a 2nd disk, containing the source code and media files, which would then be shared with 2 web servers, one configured as a CDN server and one with the main website and backend.  The backend would modify/add/delete media files, and the CDN server would supply them to the browser when requested.

My problem arises when reading that the Persistent Disk Storage is only mountable on a single VM instance with read/write access, and if it's needed on multiple instances it can be mounted only in write access.  I need to have one of the instances with read/write access with the others (possibly many) with read only access.

Would you be able to suggest ways or methods on how to implement such a system on the GCP, or if it's not possible at all?

Comment: Maybe setting up a NFS server/ client with shared directories will work in your case?

Comment: That seems to be the "only" solution at the moment.  There seems to be another possible solution to be that of mounting a storage bucket, through either a third party application or a closed beta service that google offer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible.

But, you can create a Single-Node File Server and mount it as a read and write disk on other VMs.

GCP has documentation on [how to create a single-Node File Server](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/docs/single-node-fileserver)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using persistent (which as you said, only alows a single RW mount or many read-only) is to use Cloud Storage - which can be [mounted through FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse).